# Capybara "can't find" text field, yet fills it in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

In my integration specs, I log users in with this:

```
fill_in "session_email", :with => user.email
fill_in "session_password", :with => password
click_button "submit"
```

Capybara fails those tests with `Unable to find field "session_email"`. The strange thing is, it actually fills in those fields and successfully logs the user in (I can see the output from the sessions controller, and when I use selenium I can see it working). But the tests fail.

The log-in thing opens in a bootstrap modal.

I'm using capybara (2.1.0) and capybara-webkit (1.0.0).

Has anyone else experienced this? What's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and switching to capybara-webkit fixed it for me.  I was using bootstrap as well, so not sure if Selenium doesn't like bootstrap or what, but webkit worked for me